# location.href security concern

Tags: javascript, html, security

This is my page test.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(location.href);
</script>
```

When I access test.html with the URL `http://example.com/test.html?test=<script>alert('xss')</script>` I get this output :

```
http://example.com/test.html?test=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27xss%27)%3C/script%3E
```

So clearly, location.href isn't only returning a string of the URL as mentionned [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) :

> Return Value: A String, representing the entire URL of the page, including the protocol (like http://)

it returns a string of an encoded version of the URL.

So my question is : is it safe to do `document.write(location.href);`? Will a malicious user could put an XSS payload in there?

Let's assume this is not printed into a `<script>`, `<a>` or any HTML tag, so you have to pass your tag into the location.href as I did.

**EDIT** : I think I should mention that I'm a security analyst. I am trying to exploit it so I can demonstrate to my client that this is not a good practice, but I couldn't find a way to do so. So, no need to lecture me.

Comment: xss can occur ANYTIME you dump "foreign" data into your page. doesn't matter where it came from - if it's from "outside", it's theoretically vulnerable. and that includes data you've generated YOURSELF.

Comment: `location.href` is *completely* untrusted. You want to start injecting that in the page without escaping, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Just because your browser has [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) that particular url (you will see the same in the location bar), that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Also, please don't use `document.write`, it's very inefficient (as it triggers a reparse). Instead use the DOM API (`document.createElement` etc).

Comment: *"So clearly, location.href isn't only returning a string of the URL as mentionned here :"* - but it **is** returning just a string. **You** are the one writing it to the document with `document.write`

Comment: @Bergi This is not true in every browser for the location bar. But it is probably done in background tho.

Comment: @Crayon Violent You get me wrong, I know it return a string. As I said, it doesn't just return the URL string, it return the encoded URL string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://example.com/test.html?test=<script>alert('xss')</script>` is an invalid URL. Browsers' location fields do not limit themselves only to valid URLs — they will accept almost anything, including invalid characters in the path, query string, and fragment, while parsing the input URL. The request sent to the server is a serialised version of the parsed URL, and that *is* always a valid URL, obtained by percent encoding characters that cannot legally be present in the respective parts of the URL.

The URL is an abstract concept: `location.href` returns a string that is semantically equivalent to the string used to navigate the browser to that resource — it is not necessarily the same string. Until recently, per spec, the only requirement was that the string returned be a representation of the URL, with no requirement as to *what* possible representation (and there are plenty!).

That all said, some schemes are parsed differently. Observe what `data:text/html,<script>alert(location.href);</script>` produces — an alert of that exact string, at least in Firefox 38 and Chrome 42. I can't find any navigable HTTP/HTTPS URL that will result in a `<` being output by `location.href`, but it would be naïve to assume no such URL exists.